# Metric Space (Continuity)

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Q- Let $f : N \to Q$ is a bijective function then f is continuous but inverse function $f$ is not continuous at any point of $Q$ .. (Exercise Problem)

my argument -> claim $1^{st}$ - $f$ is continuos - let $c$ be any point of $N$, i.e $|x-c|<\dfrac{1}{2}$ then for any $\epsilon >0$, whenever $|x-c|<\dfrac{1}{2}$ then  $|f(x)-f(c)|=|f(c)-f(c)|=0<\epsilon$ so this delta will work for all $c$ belongs to $N$  and it is independent of point as well as epsilon .so $f$ will be uniformly continuos and $f:N\to Q$ is a UC function. Am i correct? I don't need the bijective part to prove the continuity? Since it is given that $f$ is bijective so inverse function exists from $Q \to N$ which is also one-one and onto also, but I can't proceed further. How to show it is not continuous at any point.

Comment: Please write in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I don't understand the question, please write correctly the claim and then your attempt of proof.

Comment: You proof of continuity and uniform continuity of $f$ is correct. Continuity is following from the fact that $\mathbb{N}$ is discrete and nothing else is needed. To show that the inverse of $f$ can't be continuous show that if it were then a point of $\mathbb{Q}$ would be open. This is direct from the definition of continuity that inverse image of open sets should be open. Your definition of continuity is probably the one about the limit. Take a convergent sequence of different rationals $r_n\to r$ with rational $r$. Then $f^{-1}(r_n)$ has a limit. Since $\mathbb{N}$ is discrete, then  ...

Comment: $f^{-1}(r_n)$ is eventually constant. But this contradicts that $f$ is bijective.

Comment: Thank you , i get the idea .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me rewrite your question in more understandable way:

> Let $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ be standard naturals and rationals respectively with usual topologies. Let $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Q}$ be a bijection. Then $f$ is continuous but $f^{-1}$ is not continuous at any point.

*Proof.* "$f$ is continuous" is pretty trivial. $\mathbb{N}$ is discrete so every function $f:\mathbb{N}\to X$ is continuous. For that you just have to realize that every subset $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ is open, in particular $f^{-1}(U)$ for open $U\subseteq\mathbb{Q}$.

"$f^{-1}$ is not continuous at any point" Indeed, assume that $f^{-1}$ is continuous at $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ and let $(a_n)\subseteq\mathbb{Q}$ be a sequence convergent to $\mathbb{Q}$. Then $f^{-1}(a_n)$ is a convergent sequence. Since $\mathbb{N}$ is discrete then $f^{-1}(a_n)$ has to be eventually constant. And since $f^{-1}$ is injective then $(a_n)$ has to be eventually constant as well. But we can always find a sequence that is convergent to $q$ that is not eventually constant, namely $a_n=q+\frac{1}{n}$. Contradiction. Hence $f^{-1}$ is not continuous at $q\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Thank you , but any subset of N is open and closed in N ?? Am i right ?? how to claim this mathematically , i visualize this but writing in A intersection  N  form , but very nice answer , i got it ..

Comment: @user534210 yes, every subset is both open and closed. If points are open then everything is open because every subset is a (possibly infinite) union of points. So all you have to show (depending on your definition of topology on $\mathbb{N}$) is that points are open.